# remove spell check on input WITH JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, dom, spell-checking, dom-manipulation

i have a JavaScript program that make input and a want to remove spell check.

```
let inp = document.createElement('input');
inp.placeholder = "enter line of code";
inp.autocomplete = "off";
//did not work
inp.spellcheck = "false";
```

i tried using `inp.spellcheck = "false";` and it did not work
however just spellcheck="false" on a input worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you work with the JavaScript DOM `spellcheck` **property** (as opposed to the  HTML `spellcheck` **attribute**), you need to assign an actual **boolean value, not a string**.

```js
const inp = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('input'));
inp.placeholder = "enter line of code";
inp.autocomplete = "off";
inp.spellcheck = false; // not "false" which is a string
```

Answer (score 1):

Set an attribute instead.

```js
const inp = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('input'));
inp.placeholder = "enter line of code";
inp.autocomplete = "off";
inp.setAttribute('spellcheck', 'false');
```